# Change All Other Models' Material to the Selected Model's Material

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am experimenting around the vertex shader of 3D models. My problem is I am having the difficulty of changing all other models' material to the selected model's material. Here, I have 4 models in each viewport. If I had selected the bottom left of the model (v1), the rest of the models' material will change accordingly to the selected model's. In the Model Selection code, I had implemented the logic behind it but it did not update all other models. Below, it is assumed that are 4 vertex shaders and 4 model creations. Please advise. Thank you =)

[image]

**Main**

```
function init() {
container = document.getElementById('container');

// scene
scene = new THREE.Scene();

defineViewports();
initCameras();

// shader property
var shaderProp = {
    uniforms: {
        displacement: {
            type: "f",
            value: 0.0
        }
    },
    vertexShader: vertexShader(),
    fragmentShader: fragmentShader()
};

var shaderMaterial1 = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(shaderProp);

//object loaders with shader properties
var objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
objectLoader.load("male_model_object.json", function(object) {
    //if you want to add your custom material
    object.traverse(function (child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
            child.material = shaderMaterial1;
        }
    });

    object.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    scene.add(object);
    objects.push(object);
    materials.push(shaderMaterial1);
});

// shader property
var shaderProp = {
    uniforms: {         
        displacement: {
            type: "f",
            value: 0.0
        }
    },
    vertexShader: vertexShader2(),
    fragmentShader: fragmentShader()
};

var shaderMaterial2 = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(shaderProp);

//object loaders with shader properties
var objectLoader2 = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
objectLoader2.load("male_model_object.json", function(object) {
    //if you want to add your custom material
    object.traverse(function (child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
            child.material = shaderMaterial2;
        }
    });

    object.position.set(500, 14, 0);
    scene.add(object);
    objects.push(object);
    materials.push(shaderMaterial2);
});

// shader property
var shaderProp = {
    uniforms: {         
        displacement: {
            type: "f",
            value: 0.0
        }
    },
    vertexShader: vertexShader3(),
    fragmentShader: fragmentShader()
};

var shaderMaterial3 = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(shaderProp);

//object loaders with shader properties
var objectLoader3 = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
objectLoader3.load("male_model_object.json", function(object) {
    //if you want to add your custom material
    object.traverse(function (child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
            child.material = shaderMaterial3;
        }
    });

    object.position.set(0, 514, 0);
    scene.add(object);
    objects.push(object);
    materials.push(shaderMaterial3);
});

// shader property
var shaderProp = {
    uniforms: {         
        displacement: {
            type: "f",
            value: randomDisplacementValue()
        }
    },
    vertexShader: vertexShader4(),
    fragmentShader: fragmentShader()
};

var shaderMaterial4 = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(shaderProp);

//object loaders with shader properties
var objectLoader4 = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
objectLoader4.load("male_model_object.json", function(object) {
    //if you want to add your custom material
    object.traverse(function (child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
            child.material = shaderMaterial4;
        }
    });

    object.position.set(500, 514, 0);
    scene.add(object);
    objects.push(object);
    materials.push(shaderMaterial4);
});

//fps
stats = new Stats();
stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
container.appendChild(stats.domElement);

//renderer
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

window.addEventListener('updateSize', updateSize, false);
window.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
window.addEventListener('keypress', onDocumentKeyPress, false);}
```

**Model Selection**

```
function onDocumentKeyPress(event) {
switch(event.keyCode) {
    // enter
    case 13:
        if(selectedIndex >= 0) {
            // TODO: LOGIC BEHIND GETTING THE EQUATION OF SELECTED MODEL
            var shader = objects[selectedIndex].children[0].material.vertexShader;

            for(var j = 0; j < objects.length; ++j) {
                for(var i = 0; i < materials.length; ++i) {
                    materials[i].vertexShader = shader;
                    materials[i].needsUpdate = true;
                }
            }
        }
}}
```

**Renderer**

```
function render() {
updateSize();
for ( var i = 0; i < views.length; ++i ) {
    view = views[i];
    camera = view.camera;

    //view.updateCamera( camera );
    var left   = Math.floor(windowWidth  * view.left);
    var bottom = Math.floor(windowHeight * view.bottom);
    var width  = Math.floor(windowWidth  * view.width);
    var height = Math.floor(windowHeight * view.height);
    renderer.setViewport(left, bottom, width, height);
    renderer.setScissor(left, bottom, width, height);
    renderer.setScissorTest(true);
    renderer.setClearColor(view.background);

    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}}
```

Comment: You can't change a material's vertex shader. But you can do this: `mesh.material = differentMaterial`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set materials as var reference outside the model and reach by this reference when you need to force the change. Material change will be applied to all models using this material.

```
var shaderMaterial1 = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(shaderProp);
var shaderMaterial2 = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(shaderProp);

var objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
    objectLoader.load("male_model_object.json", function(object) {
        object.traverse(function (child) {
          if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
              child.material = shaderMaterial;
          }
        }
    });
    scene.add(object);

function onDocumentKeyPress(event) {
...
    for(var j = 0; j < objects.length; ++j) {
            for(var i = 0; i < materials.length; ++i) {
                materials[i] = shaderMaterial2;
                materials[i].needsUpdate = true;
            }
    }
...

}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? I am still kinda lost. Thank you =)

Comment: I had updated my code in the question but I still can't get the correct result. Is it because of the logic has to be applied to all 4 models?

Comment: Im not sure if you can edit shader material params. Try to switch to another created sahader material instead or create new.

Comment: However, I am not creating new. I have 4 models. Each model has its respective shader material. So, if I would select either one of the models, the rest of the models' shader material should change to the selected model's shader material =)